# Workbook_Open() sheet.activate error in protected view when enable editing

Tags: vba, excel

I have problems with *sheets.activate* contained into *Workbook_Open()* when the file is in *protected mode* (because downloaded from internet). As soon as you "Enable Editing" the Workbook_Open() is executed and the error comes out.

If I use this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets(2).Activate
End Sub
```

I have this error:
*Runtime Error 1004 Activate method of Worksheet class failed*

Reading in some other discussion i tried using the *Workbook_Activate()* method which works if I have only one simple activation in all my project. The previous example could be fixed if I use:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
a = True
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()
If a Then
    Sheets(2).Activate
    a = False
End If
End Sub
```

but it partially fix the problem, this code could work but next time i have another sheets.activate in my project the error comes out again, (i.e. if i click a button into a panel or if i run other routines).

This error comes out only the first time you open the file, if you stop the debugger, close the file without saving and reopen the file the error doesn't come out again but i would avoid it to come out the first time

Thanks in advance

Comment: There isn't really a better option that I'm aware of, other than perhaps having a startup sheet that says to reopen the workbook.

Comment: instead of using it inside a acivate event use it inside a function and call the function inside the open event

Comment: i am not sure what is wrong still...

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it is a known issue:
[Object Model calls may fail from WorkbookOpen event when exiting Protected View](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2745652/object-model-calls-may-fail-from-workbookopen-event-when-exiting-protected-view)

It says ...

> **Resolution**
>   You can workaround the issue by either :-
>
> 1. If the location from where the workbooks are being open is trusted, add that location to the Excel's Trusted Locations.
> 2. Defer Object Model calls to outside of the WorkbookOpen event to WorkbookActivate event.

Code example to defer object model calls

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents oApp As Excel.Application
Private bDeferredOpen As Boolean

Private Sub oApp_WorkbookActivate(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    If bDeferredOpen Then
        bDeferredOpen = False
        Call WorkbookOpenHandler(Wb)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub oApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    Dim oProtectedViewWindow As ProtectedViewWindow
    On Error Resume Next
        'The below line will throw error (Subscript out of range) if the workbook is not opened in protected view.
        Set oProtectedViewWindow = oApp.ProtectedViewWindows.Item(Wb.Name)
    On Error GoTo 0 'Reset error handling

    If oProtectedViewWindow Is Nothing Then
        bDeferredOpen = False
        Call WorkbookOpenHandler(Wb)
    Else
        'Delay open actions till the workbook gets activated.
        bDeferredOpen = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub WorkbookOpenHandler(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    'The actual workbook open event handler code goes here...
End Sub
```

Comment: I put the code to the class module but it didn't work

Comment: Me also, this is not working

Answer (score 0):

Check the file properties before you open it. If it comes from the internet, there is usually a "Unprotect" checkbox on the properties page you can check to unprotect it, then it should open like normal.

There is also a "Read-only" checkbox that might help you too. Make sure the file is not read only.

Just do this before you open it.