# Enable editing after Protected View loses Worbook focus

Tags: excel, vba

I created an Excel VBA program. When I download it from the internet (or e-mail) it gets opened in **'Read-only mode' (Protected View)**. When I click **'Enable editing'** I receive this error:

> method worksheets of object _global failed'

and the error is on this piece of code:

```
sheetsNr = Worksheets.Count
```

it WORKS if I change it to:

```
sheetsNr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

But that means that I would need to go through my whole program, and it is pretty complex, an put `ThisWorkbook.` everywhere.

I guess that after **'Enable editing'** the Workbook gets restarted and somehow loses the focus of the workbook and therefore the references are not valid.
Is there a an option to keep the focus on the workbook to avoid the problem?

There is also a duplicate question but whitout a solution:
[Workbook_Open() sheet.activate error in protected view when enable editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42646125/workbook-open-sheet-activate-error-in-protected-view-when-enable-editing)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the file properties before you open it? If it comes from the internet, there is usually a "Unprotect" checkbox on the properties page you can check to unprotect it, then it should open like normal. There is also a "Read-only" checkbox that might help you too. Just do this before you open it.

Otherwise, if that is the only issue, you can do a global replace:

Replace this

```
= Worksheets.Count
```

With this

```
= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
```

That will replace it in all sheets, all modules... just make sure you select ALL

Comment: Thanks, but it is not just about Worksheets.count. It is about everywhere where I use Worksheets(), and I am affraid of possible bugs if I skip something or change something that I didn't want to.

Comment: Well you didn't mention that it was not only the worksheet count. See my updated answer.

Comment: Unchecking something in settings can not help because then everybody new user who downloads the file should uncheck it. That is bad user experience because of different IT-knowledge of people. I need just a solution to avoid the problem with the lost focus or global object.

Comment: Then you have to go thru all the code and fix every line. You should have realized that worksheets should be fully qualified when you wrote the code.

Comment: The only other alternative would be to move the code to an XLAM file (Excel Add-In) instead, and not include the code in the workbook that you are emailing. But fixing the code might actually be less work. At least that's what they pay you for, right?